# Global context and "this" in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Following JS code executes an anonimous function and defines a function met() and makes it visible from the global context:

```
(function(GLOB){

    GLOB.met = function(s) {
        console.log(s);
    }

})(this);


met("Hi!");
```

When run in a browser, works fine and displays "Hi!" on the console.
However, when run in Node.js, the last line throws the error "met is not defined".

When I now change the last line in:

```
this.met("Hi!");
```

it works well on Node.js as well.

Why the first version does not work on Node?

Comment: this code sample works fine for me when it is in a global scope... check whether you run it in global scope and not in module one or that it is not wrapped in some outer closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This" is not global in the outerscope of nodejs. Instead use global.varName.

The best practice is to use GLOBAL.VAR_NAME so that you know not to do it often.

If you want some consistency with the browser I'd recommend browserify as it let's you use global on the client side, as well as require and even merges your js for  you! Just my two cents.

Comment: this does not really fit the fact that writing this === global returns true in the global scope...

Comment: So, browserify would replace require.js on the client side?
Is that a widely accepted and stable tool?

Comment: Yes browserify is used in industry by companies like yahoo. Like I said its accomplished by merging all the files so if you need unique files for each page or something its not ideal but can be configured. Most of my projects are spas with routers, so I use my merged CSS bundle and my browserify bundle and then that's only two synchronous calls during page load. (Although I've done some other magic to automatically include parts of CSS libraries and such, and if you want the best you can dump the code in script tags and style tags so that your entire page loads in one file!)